# Portable screen for USB camera

Tags: hardware

apologies if this is not the correct place to ask this question.

I need to use a USB camera with a long extension (something like this http://www.lightinthebox.com/5m-usb-waterproof-borescope-endoscope-mini-inspection-snake-tube-home-camera_p344225.html) in the field without a laptop. I don't necessarily need to record anything - only view the image on a screen. Is it possible to buy a battery-operated screen / monitor compatible with these USB webcams / borescopes? Or even a cheap tablet computer? Basically, a cheaper option than buying a handheld inspection camera (http://www.toolstop.co.uk/ridgid-micro-ca-100-36738-hand-held-inspection-camera-p14976) with £££s worth of extension tubes?

Comment: This is off topic here but, as @ClintGrimsley has suggested, I would recommend you check out the raspberry pi.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about alternatives for handheld inspection cameras and not Audio or Video production.

Answer (score 1):

Pair a [raspberry pi](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?gclid=CJqbzLyV_rsCFYQ7OgodiSwABw&Item=N82E16813142001&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-_-pla-_-Embedded%20Solutions-_-N82E16813142001&ef_id=UMDrTAAAVloZgDXH:20140114171542%3as) with one of these [3.5 inch lcd displays](http://www.afterpartz.com/us/3-5-tft-lcd-color-screen-car-rearview-monitor-dvd-vcr.html) and that should bring you under the cost of one of those handheld displays.

Finding a decent way to enclose it would be the difficult part.

Comment: check out http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ for info regarding OS etc.